# Global dark mode switch in arch

Tags: arch-linux, scripting, colors, theme

I am looking for a way to have a shortcut to toggle from light/dark mode on my Arch (Artix) system ,with just a window manager.

The only thing that comes to mind is to grep the configs of every application i have , change the colour scheme, and reload them (somehow...). So before i start this huge effort project i would like to know if someone already figured it out .A git link would be really helpful!
.If not , how would you go about doing it?

Comment: Sadly no, as i already mentioned, I don't use a desktop environment, so not all my apps are unified under it.

Comment: Some apps i use include : Nvim, Qutebrowser , Qtile , alacrity, kitty etc

Comment: There. is. no. switch. whether. you. are. using. a. DE. or. not. The earlier question and answers to it make that abundantly clear.

Comment: Ok , i know that, that's why i am willing to code a script changing configs like i said previously. All i wanted to know was if someone thought of a better way to do it before me.

Comment: If you're willing to do that you may as well codify dark mode in Linux globally via some interface, e.g. dbus. It sucks Linux doesn't have it. Of course patching multiple applications and DEs is obviously required.